# ggplot: Normalize starting point of line graphs over time

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, normalize

I have a graph in which I am comparing intensity changes over time for multiple objects. My y-axis is the intensity value, my x-axis is the timepoint, and a have a line plotted for each object.

I am trying to normalize the data where at time 0 the intensity for each object starts at 0 so that any changes in intensity can be compared equally.

I don't believe scale_y_continuous will work because it seems to only show the y-axis starting at 0, not physically moving all data points to the same level.

I am very new to coding. I'm currently working in R studio with ggplot2, tidyverse, and ggforce libraries. My data I'm working out of is a CSV file. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You need to modify the data to normalize it to 0, not do it in the plotting code. This means just subtracting the first element of each column from the whole column. Without a specific reproducible example, we can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.